# Cannot load generic password from iOS Keychain (errSecNotAvailable -25291)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, keychain

This happens on iOS 13.3 (iPhone 11)

I developed a react native iOS app which saves/loads data into/from keychain via https://github.com/mCodex/react-native-sensitive-info/blob/master/ios/RNSensitiveInfo/RNSensitiveInfo.m

My read/write keychain options is below, it never changes and works well since day1

```
const defaultOptions: RNSensitiveInfoOptions = {
  touchID: true,
  kSecAccessControl: 'kSecAccessControlBiometryAny',
  kSecUseOperationPrompt: 'We will store data securely on your device.',
  sharedPreferencesName: 'sensitive',
  keychainService: 'sensitive',
};
```

Recently one of my clients complain about the data cannot be retrieved from keychain because of `errSecNotAvailable                       = -25291,    /* No keychain is available. You may need to restart your computer. */`

I thought there might be something wrong happened to keychain, so I tried set a single key/value item with the same option (so the `kSecAttrService` and `kSecClass` are same with business related items): 'foo' -> 'bar'. And I can load this value out via the same option.

I did more experiences:

1. if I read a key doesn't exist, the keychain API will return error `errSecItemNotFound -25300`
2. if I read a business related key, the keychain API return error `errSecNotAvailable -25291`
3. I jailbreak this iPhone and use https://github.com/ptoomey3/Keychain-Dumper to dump the items but it prompt (although the phone is unlock):

```
[INFO] No Generic Password Keychain items found.
[HINT] You should unlock your device!
```

4. I copied Keychain-2.db from device to local computer and using sqlite DB to query the generic password items, looks like they are there (but as they are encrypted, i am not sure 100%):
   [image]

I am expecting someone could suggest:

1. why this issue could happen?
2. is there any possibility I can restore the keychain data?